# В калькуляторе реализовать запрет ввод символов кроме тех, что есть в калкьуляторе

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, калькулятор

Реализую калькулятор на Django. В нем будут кнопки, которые будут добавлять свой определенный символ в выражение, а также возможность пользователю самому написать выражение в строку. Подскажите, как мне реализовать проверку на то, ввел ли пользователь символы, которые запрещены? Я планировал сделать set, в котором содержатся все цифры, а также все возможные знаки (+ - * / sqrt ^ и др.). Как мне сделать так, чтобы программа проверяла выражение и если она находила символ, которого нету в сете, она выдавала ошибку? Слышал что то про проверку нахождения подмножества во множестве, но это же помоему не то, что мне нужно?

Comment: У вас опечатка в заголовке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, хотя сложно по описанию понять, но могу примерно объяснить, как такое делается.

В Python есть оператор членства `in`, позволяющий проверить наличие переменной в списке/кортеже/сете/строке и т. п. C помощью него можно реализовать проверку наличия каки-либо других символов, кроме допустимых, в выражении, переданном калькулятору. Пример:

```
vyr_good = '1-5+3'
vyr_bad = '1+2/b'
s = '0123456789+-*/'
validate = lambda vyr: all([i in s for i in vyr])
print(validate(vyr_good))                            # Вывод: True
print(validate(vyr_bad))                             # Вывод: False
```

`s` — множество допустимых символов. `vyr_good` и `vyr_bad` соответственно, допустимое и недопустимое выражения. Функция `all` проверяет, что все значения в переданном ей списке равны True. При помощи спискового включения мы создаем список, в котором все элементы будут равны True только если каждый член выражения будет в строке-валидаторе. Эта функция для удобства заключена в лямбду.